# Komodo editor tabs disappeared - bug?

Tags: komodo

Komodo used to show me tabs of open files, but one day they disappeared. I can't find an option to turn them back on. I use the side menu now but it's much less convenient. I tried in the "View" > "Tabs & Sidebars" menu but can't find an option to turn tabs on.

There's also a tab icon button in the icon row at the top of the open file window but clicking it only opens the sidebar.

Edit: someone answered that there should be an specific option for this, but it doesn't appear my in my menus. screenshots here: imgur.com/a/PylIB

Komodo Edit, version 8.5.4, build 14424, platform macosx. Built on Wed Aug 13 23:56:46 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle tabs from `View > Toolbars > Show Editor Tabs`. Or by right clicking your toolbar and clicking "Show Editor Tabs".

Comment: I don't have either of these options. screenshots here: http://imgur.com/a/PylIB

Komodo Edit, version 8.5.4, build 14424, platform macosx. Built on Wed Aug 13 23:56:46 2014.

Comment: You're running an older version of Komodo. You need the "View Editor Tabs" at the bottom of your first screenshot.